# sizeToFit() not working properly with attributedText

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, nsattributedstring

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //cell init
        //set values to cell property
        let str2 = NSString(format: "%@", (displayArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("username") as? String)!)
        let attrStr2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str2 as String)
        attrStr2.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)!, range: NSMakeRange(0, str2.length ))
        topCell.username.attributedText = attrStr2

        topCell.username.sizeToFit()

        topCell.title.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        topCell.username.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        //some calculation which is not affecting username.frame.size.width
        return topCell;

}
```

and here is my tableView
[image]

You can see label with yellow background, 
And yes, autolayout is disable, so I think my code is fine but not working as expected.

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If Autolayout is disabled, where do you set the position for `username` UILabel in your cell?

Comment: @noir_eagle, From xib of custom cell